# Regex match everything that ends with a dot

Tags: bash, devops

I have commits like `[version-update]` Version has been updated in bla bla repository in branch develop to `5.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I need to match everything with `.`. What regex I can use

Comment: What is your expected output and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The dot has to be escaped and $ represents the end of the string so

```
\.$
```